# Duplicate master Google Slides deck + Populate it from Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

I have two scripts that work well separately but I need to combine them.

What I am trying to achieve is that from a Google Sheets, someone will run a script and:

1. A copy of a master Google Slides deck will be made and the name will be updated based on a sheet called 'Generate'
2. This copy will be updated with values from the sheet called 'Data', using placeholders

For point 1 I have this code:

```
function createFolderAndFiles() {
  const templateGetStarted = '<ID OF MY TEMPLATE DECK>';

let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Generate');
let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

let wbrDate = data[1][0];
let getStarted = data[1][1];


  DriveApp.getFileById(templateGetStarted).makeCopy(`WBR - ${wbrDate}`)
}
```

And for point 2 I have this code:

```
function fillTemplate() {

 var PRESENTATION_ID = "<THE ID OF THE JUST CREATED COPY OF THE TEMPLATE DECK IN POINT 1>";

 var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(PRESENTATION_ID);

 var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data').getDataRange().getValues();

 values.forEach(function(row) {
   var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
   var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
   presentation.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
 });

}
```

So as I mentioned, they work great separetely. I just need to find a way to combine them both into 1 function that you can run and a copy of the template deck will be made and it will be filled automatically with data from the spreadsheet.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try meeting your last line of the first function and first line of the second one

```
var PRESENTATION_ID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateGetStarted).makeCopy(`WBR - ${wbrDate}`).getId()
```

Comment: I wanted to say merging instead of meeting, I'm glad you arrived at the correct solution!